# Elegant implementation of relative date ranges in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, datetime, localization, nsdate

I want to display a date range for my users. I need something smart, but localization independent method for displaying only the necessary parts of the range end like this:

`2017-jan-1 to 2017-feb-2` → `2017-jan-1 to feb-2`

`2017-jan-1 to 2017-jan-2` → `2017-jan-1 to 2`

`2017-jan-1 to 2018-jan-2` → `2017-jan-1 to 2018-jan-2`

I could write several `if`s to check if the components are the same, but then I had to write format strings by hand, which I don't want because other localizations need other month/day orders.

Is there a system API similar to `doesRelativeDateFormatting` or a CocoaPods library for this? How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSDateFormatter` method [`+dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdateformatter/1408112-dateformatfromtemplate) addresses the point at which you thought your approach failed. Given a template specifying the parts of a date you wish included; the example Apple uses being day name, day number and month; it returns an appropriate format string for the locale and user preferences.

HTH

Comment: In the `template` you should specify the exact format (incl. the punctation and order) of the date string, or do I miss something?

Comment: You missed something, look at the example in the method's description and follow the link to the formatting guide.